# Can drawer slides be used for a shelf?

Tags: woodworking

Can I use a drawer slide for a pull out shelf (instead of a drawer) and does it matter if the wood is 3/4" or 1/2" thick?  I have a 13" wide x 26" long x 1/2" thick shelf and a standard 12" full extension ball bearing draw slide I want to mount to it.  When I mount slide to shelf I will have an inch where no slide is attached.  Will this still be a full extension or will there be an inch left of the shelf that remains under the top of the desk?

Comment: sounds good, go for it

Comment: The drawer slides do not have a detector to know what they're attached to. They will not fail nor revolt if you attach them to a shelf, tray, bin, or other contraption instead of a drawer. They're referred to as "drawer slides" because "drawer/shelf/tray slides" is simply too much of a mouthful to say and/or print on marketing & packaging material.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the depth (front to back) of your shelf is will make no difference. It could be the depth of the desktop, maybe 2' or more, but using a 12" slide, it will only slide 12". If your shelf is 13" deep, then fixing the slides to its front end, and the slides to the front end of the desk, will mean it'll close level with the desk edge, and open leaving 1" still under the desk top.

To open fully, you'd need to fix the slides so that 1" of the shelf stuck out when closed - maybe not a good idea. Let's face it, we don't always need to open even fully opening drawers completely.

Fixing into 1/2" wood will depend on what that wood is. I'd be wary of fixing into 1/2" chipboard without using proper fittings, dowels or several extra screws.

I did similar for a slide out keyboard (61 note electronic) and used 9mm ply for the base, with edges beefed up with 1"x1" real wood, screwed through the ply underneath, and the slides screwed into that. Never had any problems, and it's a heavy keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use a drawer slide for a pull out shelf (instead of a drawer)

yes

> and does it matter if the wood is 3/4" or 1/2" thick?

The thickness of the wood should probably be taller than the drawer slide. else you will get edge walls.

> I have a 13" wide x 26" long x 1/2" thick shelf and a standard 12" full extension ball bearing draw slide I want to mount to it. When I mount slide to shelf I will have an inch where no slide is attached.
> Will this still be a full extension or will there be an inch left of the shelf that remains under the top of the desk?

If the drawer slide offers 12" of movement then there will be 12" more exposed when the shelf is out than when it is in.  If you start with 1" exposed then the finish will be 13" exposed.